# C++ sublime text plugin code navigation

Tags: c++, plugins, ide, sublimetext3

I am looking for a feature that i will explain below. Please let me know if there are any plugins that allow you to do this in Sublime Text 3 and if this is a normal feature for an IDE.
Lets say you have:

```
Class A{
    ....
    Foo member_foo;
}

member_foo.Init();
```

With sublime text when I goto defn on the above line, it will list all the Init() functions in my entire project(there are many). **I want it to go to Foo's Init() function obviously.** Is there a plugin that will add this functionality in sublime text? Is this normal functionality in C++ IDEs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime provides some intellisense out of the box,
but as you've noted, it is not actually parsing the C++ and has some shortcomings.

You can install the [Rtags plugin](https://github.com/rampage644/sublime-rtags).
I've also used [EasyClangComplete](https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete).

Another tip that may help you, is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
This will let you jump to symbols in a project.